# How to navigate to a view controller on a new storyboard file in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I got a source code for an existing app. throughout the app the developer didn't use storyboard for the user interface but rather he used interface builder `xib` files. As a new developer, i don't know how to develop `iOS` apps in `xcode` using `xib` files for `viewcontrollers`, i `learnt` the storyboard way. Now I want to add more screens to the apps source code, i created a new storyboard file to define my new screens, how do I navigate to the entry point of this new storyboard from a button action i defined in one of the `xib` files so that i can easily implement my features.
while searching i got some suggestions like this one

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"newStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
MyNewViewController *myVC = (MyNewViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewCont"];
```

but i dont think i understand how to implement this even if this can be in a button `IBAction` method. and besides subsequent `navigations` would be segues through the view controllers i define in the new storyboard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's right suggestion.
You should get storyboard object by its name. Then you should create your viewController using `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"..."];`
Then you may navigate to your new VC using appropriate navigation method. For example:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]
```

ViewController identifier you should set in Interface Builder under section "Identity Inspector" in field "Storyboard ID".

That code you should place in IBAction method. But better would be to extract it in separate method. Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender { 
    [self navigateToMyNewViewController];
}

- (void)navigateToMyNewViewController {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myNewStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    MyNewViewController *myNewVC = (MyNewViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNewViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

Navigation from MyNewViewController your can implement as you want. It may be segues.

Comment: What if the new storyboard's initial view is a TabBarController consisting of two viewcontrollers, how do i navigate to the TabBarViewController which will display screen based on first selected tabbar ?index

Comment: You should instantiate and push(present) TabBarController.
If initial selected VC index should be different from 0, you should write tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; before push or in TabBarController's viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2):

```
MyNewViewController *myVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_VC_NAME_HERE"];
```

This will instantiate your ViewController, from here you can present it like so

```
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil]
```

[image]

The image shows where you set the storyboard name that you're referring to

Comment: What if the first screen is a TabBarViewController, would the code change, because the tab bar controller has two view controllers (assuming two tabs)?

Comment: Use Storyboard ID for the TabBarController, like you would do to call a viewController. This will instantiate the TabBar to display, which is set up to show the two viewControllers from within the TabBar as you say

Answer (score 1):

Try This it's working for me ,

**Use below line of code :**

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"bundle:nil];
  LoginViewController *loginVC = (LoginViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginVC animated:YES];
```

We need to set **storyboard id** as per mention in below,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate one `storyboard` to another `storybord`:

first you import your `viewcontroller` class to `appdelegate`.h

```
AppDelegate *appDelegateTemp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

            appDelegateTemp.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Answer (score -1):

Like the way you use storyboard, use

```
    MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainVC animated:YES];
```